# Unable to find class annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Why does this code print 0?

```
@Table(name = "source")
public class SourceDetails implements DatabaseEntity{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SourceDetails.class.getAnnotations().length);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: is it javax.persistence.Table? Or your @Table ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you didn't set the retention of the annotation to runtime.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Table{
  String name();

  int intValue();
}
```

Comment: if it is the javax.persistence.Table annotation, it is set to Runtime.